# How do I tell whether my browser extensions leak personal data?

Tags: browser-extensions

According to the article [Warning: Your Browser Extensions Are Spying On You](https://www.howtogeek.com/180175/warning-your-browser-extensions-are-spying-on-you/):

> Browser add-ons for Chrome, Firefox, and probably other browsers are tracking every single page you visit and sending that data back to a third-party company that pays them for your information.
>
> [...]
>
> Millions of people are being tracked this way and they don’t have a clue.

The BBC recently wrote in the article [It is easy to expose users' secret web habits, say researchers](http://www.bbc.com/news/technology-40770393):

> The information revealed an intimate portrait of the browsing habits of people, said Ms Eckert.
>
> [...]
>
> The pair found that 95% of the data they obtained came from 10 popular browser extensions.

How do I keep myself save in this regard? Is there some white list of friendly browser extensions? To take a specific example, how do I tell whether my uBlock extension is safe?

Comment: A general rule is: if your browser is running, it's leaking data.

Comment: Depends on the browser, if it's Chrome, then it's botnet anyway.

Answer (score 1):

A technical solution to find out how talkative browser plugins are is to use a network traffic analyzer like [Wireshark](https://www.wireshark.org/). The actual traffic might be encrypted, but you can at least tell if your webbrowser suddenly makes requests to unrelated servers it did not make before.

A legal solution is to try to find the privacy policy and terms of use of a browser plugin. In most jurisdictions, companies are legally obligated to notify their users when they collect private information.